# How to provide automated Hard Drive maintenance on Windows (7-10)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, automatic-maintenance

I just had two drives go bad. Looks like faulty sectors.
But I run chkDsk regularly. Unfortunately, it's a manual process. Also, you have to look at the report and read the # of bad sectors, rather than having a simple flag that pops up only WHEN there is a problem. (Set it and forget sort of thing)

Any tips for an automated process to check for problems?

Comment: One tip perhaps --> A PowerShell script remotely querying for correlated values of event id's, keywords, etc. from the Event Viewer that runs at certain intervals on a scheduled that will send you an email when certain values exist may be helpful for a good starting point.

Comment: Search for "hd smart monitor" and take your pick.